# why is this simple code not running the if only the var

Tags: javascript, html

```
var username = prompt("Please enter username", "<Name>");
var password = prompt("Please enter password", "<Password>");

if (username != null , password != null) {
    console.log("Welcome!");
    console.log(`Hello ${username} You're Password Is : ${password}`);
}
```

Comment: `&&` instead of `,`; `&&` is boolean AND, `,` is the comma operator and does something else

Comment: Im new to javascript and is there any better way to ask the user for username and passport

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @SuperStormer *, is the comma operator and **does something else*** I keep forgetting what it does, too :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The logical AND (&&) operator (logical conjunction) for a set of operands is true if and only if all of its operands are true.
It is typically used with Boolean (logical) values. When it is, it returns a Boolean value. However, the && operator actually returns the value of one of the specified operands, so if this operator is used with non-Boolean values, it will return a non-Boolean value.

Here is your mistake, Use && operator to check both condition true

```
if (username != null && password != null)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND